# Tikkun for sex with a non jew?

Tags: gentiles, sexuality, repentance-teshuvah

The arizal says that it is a big sin to have sex with a non jew. If someone had sex with one how can he repent for that?

Comment: As a general rule the solution to any sin is repentance. Proper repentance absolves all sins. Generally, repentance consists of regret at having performed the sin, a commitment not to repeat it, with a verbal confession to God often a component as well.

Comment: Since you're asking based upon the arizal's p'sak regarding relations with a non-Jew, one would logically look at the Arizal's writings on repentance for advice on how to properly repent for such a sin. Regardless, Chazal says that death itself atones for sins that are not absolved by other punishments PROVIDED that the person repents the sin.

Comment: Tom, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your first question! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: There is some story (which I dont believe) that a person repented and he knew it was accepted because the children he had from her mysteriously died.

Comment: Please [edit] in a citation for your claims about what the Ari wrote.

Comment: To repent for any sin: Have remorse. [Ask forgiveness from those harmed if applicable and make financial restitution to them if applicable.] Confess orally to God. Promise not to do it again. (It's a deceptively simple process.)

Comment: @newcomer that is extremely disturbing. לא יומתו אבות על בנים (I am aware one can find some seeming exceptions, but still...)

Comment: הקרא רפוקד עון אבות על בכיס מייד בבנים קטנים
 מרם שנעשו בני י״ג שנה ויזם א׳ דקיי״ל דבכים קטנים
 מתים בעין אבותיהם. עיי׳ רמב״ם פ״ו מהל׳ תשובה
 ה״א. ועיי׳ פר״מ או״מ בא״א סי׳ רכ״ה ס״ק ה׳ דרייק דאין
 הבנים מתים במון אמותיהם מדכתיב פוקד עון אבוס על
 בנים ולא מון אמות משמע דמפרש ג״כ דקרא מייד
 בבנים קטנים״ ועיי׳ שבס (דף לב ע״ב) דחשיב התם
 כמה דברים שבעבורם הבנים מתים כשהם קטנים.
 ועיי׳ כתוטת (דף עב ע״א) דמוכת התם רבעון נדרים
 מתים הבנים אפילו בחטא אמותיהם. דהרי כתב התם
 נודרת ואינה מקיימת דה״ט דיוצאת ם
@mevaqesh
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_37618_86.pdf
 ל

Comment: @newcomer Although Rambam does indeed state that tremendous chiddush, your story did not specify that the children were minors. Rambam would not believe in the "divine sign" in the story anyway, so it is hard to invoke his views. Furthermore, even Rambam does not write explicitly that the children arent deserving of death. This enters the larger problem of how God executes reward and punishment given reward and punishment to individuals may interfere with each other. Punishing the rasha may help the zaddiq, etc. Regarding which we throw up our hands and concede that we cannot comprehend Him.

Comment: Shut noda bihuda give a complete schedule to a man in this case

Comment: Saying Tikkun haKlali the Ten Psalms will help a lot

Answer (score 4):

Rav Moshe Stern, the Debreciner Rav, has a responsum to a group of people who had repeated intercourse with various non-Jewish women.  After dealing with a number of other issues (such as if wearing a condom during intercourse mitigates the prohibition in some way, and which particular transgressions were involved in that case), he concludes ([Be'er Moshe 4:141-142](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14710&st=&pgnum=495), my summary/loose translation below):

> על כן, ירבו בבכי ובחרטת הלב בלב שלם ויקבלו תעניות כפי כחם וה' הטוב יסלח להם. והעיקר הוא חרטת הלב והחלטה נחושה לבל ישובו חס ושלום אל כסלם...
>
> Therefore, they should cry a lot and regret their actions sincerely, and they should accept fasts according to their strength, and Hashem the good should forgive them. The focal point should be the internal regret, and a concrete decision not to return, Chas Veshalom, to their silliness.

Answer (score 3):

Reb Moshe has about 3 teshuvos on this sort of thing, I think he is discussing teshuvah for homosexuality as far as I remember.

The issue with having sex with a non-Jew is more a hapharas bris than an issur de'oraysah, in fact the rishonim are hard put to pinpoint exactly what the issur should be.

I.e. you have violated the integrity of the Jewish people.

The gra in his peirush on the safra ditzneusah says the bris hamaor is keneged the bris ha'lashon. I.e. the tikkun al pi kabalah for hapharas bris is to do mitzvos involving the mouth, such as learning Torah and not speaking lashon hara. Which is approximately what Reb Moshe says.

Comment: Can you cite these responsa of R Moshe?