# How does one complete tshuvah for a jewish woman having a child with a non-jew?

Tags: gentiles, repentance-teshuvah, baal-teshuva, children

If a Jewish woman has a child with a non-Jewish man, is there a standard repentance process recommended in the sources? This is specifically repentance regarding having the child, not regarding [cohabitation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71424/tikkun-for-sex-with-a-non-jew) or marriage.

Comment: Welcome to MY! You may find this useful: https://www.ou.org/holidays/the_four_steps_of_repentance/

Comment: Tricia B. S., [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! I've modified the post to focus on the specific point you identified (having a child)  and removed other extraneous scenario details. If the specific scenario described in the original version of this post pertains to someone you know, I would suggest that they [consult a rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) for personal advice, which is [not something](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734) we can offer here.

Comment: "This is specifically repentance regarding having the child, not regarding cohabitation or marriage." From where have you derived that delivering the child is prohibited? I've never seen it suggested anywhere that one must abort a child conceived to a non-Jewish father.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I don't think anyone's implying that delivering the child is a sin per se, but we do [find](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.9a.5?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Chagigah.9a.5.1&lang2=bi) that it can be more difficult to repent when a child is born of an illicit union.

Comment: I think this is like any question where a competent Rav must be consulted. Beyond the very basics, the requirement depends a lot on the person's individual situation.